# MSVS C++, how to compile already-preprocessed file with *.i extension?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, compiler-flags

*Related question here:*  [How can I run the MSVC preprocessor and compiler in two separate steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757231/how-can-i-run-the-msvc-preprocessor-and-compiler-in-two-separate-steps)

I explicitly pre-process a `MyFile.cpp` (not compile) to a `MyFile.i`.  I want to later "compile" that file (explicitly skipping preprocessing would be nice, but as the related question suggests, it sounds like that is not possible with MSVS.)

PROBLEM:  The `MyFile.i` is an "unrecognized extension", and `cl.exe` assumes it is an "object file" resulting in a "no-operation".  (See Microsoft warning:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfsbakc5(v=VS.90).aspx, this warning is active for MSVS 2005, 2008, 2010).

I can't find a switch to state that it is a "source file" (not an object file).  The related question explicitly used the "`MyFile_preprocessed.cpp`" convention, but I'd really rather stay with the (more-universal) `MyFile.i` convention.

**QUESTION:  Is there a flag where I can compile a `MyFile.i` with MSVS?**

Comment: thank you so much for asking this question. microsoft is retarded beyond redemption these days. the MSDN just says "resubmit for compilation" for .i files, without mentioning exactly how to do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cl.exe` has these two flags

- `/Tc<source file>` compile file as .c
- `/Tp<source file>` compile file as .cpp

that lets you compile  files with arbitrary extension as **c** or **c++** files

I tried compiling a `main.i` with the following contents

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world \n";
    return 0;
}
```

with `cl /Tp main.i` and it works as advertised

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I cannot comprehend why in the universe does not the MSDN page tell you this is how to compile a ".i" file. All it says is you need to "resubmit .i file" for compilation, which is as useless as a pair of tits on a cow.

Comment: How can I include a preprocessor file (X.hpp.i file) in another source(.cc/.cpp) file?