# stdin as input file for MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have a custom tool that I want to run as part of the compile process, between the preprocessing and compiling. For GCC, I do:

```
gcc [options] -E source.c | mytool | gcc [options] -c source.o -xc -
```

However, I haven't figured out how to do something similar for MSVC. Currently I have

```
cl.exe [options] /EP source.c | mytool.exe > temp.c
cl.exe [options] /c temp.c
```

The problem here is that for every source file (thousands), I have an additional disk write/read cycle. Additionally, when MSVC outputs the .i files, they tend to get really large. Over 10MB large. So the 10MB disk I/O per file piles up really quickly.

So, my questions:

1) Is it possible to get cl.exe to read treat stdin as an input file?

2) If not, is it possible to create a memory mapped file it can read from?

3) Is there a better way to do this?

And no, "get an SSD" and "don't use MSVC" are not valid answers, sorry.

Related (but not solving the speed issue)

- [Any way to parse preprocessed source through external tool before it compiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099415/any-way-to-parse-preprocessed-source-through-external-tool-before-it-compiles?rq=1)
- [How can I run the MSVC preprocessor and compiler in two separate steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757231/how-can-i-run-the-msvc-preprocessor-and-compiler-in-two-separate-steps?rq=1)

Comment: Create a ramdisk for the temp files?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Awesome idea, but I don't have access to all systems running the build, other than through the makefiles. However, I'm probably going to do that for my own system.

Comment: IF that is for C, why add the C++ tag?

Comment: @Olaf it is for both, I just used C in the example.

Comment: Why do you care. A proper OS should do the buffering for you. Just have enough RAM available. (And it would also allow to redirect stdin/out) - no idea if Windows supports that.

Comment: @Olaf unfortunately, not working on a proper OS, but on Windows. The perf hit is very noticeable (over 100%)

Comment: FS cache will help file reading, but not file creation & write. Named FIFOs should do the trick but alas they're not here either. Would like to see answer for that question, but it appears you're quite low on options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference: I've found no way to trick `cl.exe` to read from memory instead of disk.

However, I managed to speed up the process to acceptable speed by using the GNU CPP for the first stage, then `cl.exe` just for compiling. So:

```
cpp.exe [options] source.c | mytool.exe > temp.c
cl.exe [options] temp.c
```

`cpp.exe` produces a file 5-10 times smaller than `cl.exe /E`. The trick is just to make it define `_MSC_VER` and similar instead of `__GNUC__`. I did this by using the `-undef` option to get rid of everything, then define MSFT specific ones manually. I may look into using clang as a CPP, since it can mimic MSVC.

CPP leaves the `#pragma` directives intact, so no problems with compatibility there.

---

I've now reached a performance point where the spawning of a process has a significant effect on the overall build time, so I'm looking into compiling a preprocessor into `mytool.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010, under the Propererty pages, the Configuration Properties, a section for "Custom Build Step".  Try this section.

Also search the internet for "MSDN Visual Studio custom build".

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Not using visual Studio, just the compiler binaries but it may give some ideas.